# How to configure the Laravel built-in web server?

Tags: laravel

I am running this command:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\notebook>php artisan serve
```

However I get this error:

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\notebook\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\notebook\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\notebook\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\notebook\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 2):

After creating a project or cloning existing one you should run `composer install` command which will install all dependecies and will create `autoload.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

That is an import error.

Everytime you have one of these, you should try to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Most of the time, this command will fix your imports.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have installed the required dependencies yet. You should do so using the `composer` package manager, like so:

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer install
```